# how can i trigger an action when a variable change it value in this case time?

Tags: python

I need to detect when the minutes of the clock/time change and do something,
This is mi code so far, for the clock but still can figuruate out in python how to detect the value has change and do action after. Any help will be apreciated i come from  a c++ backgorund my implementations seems so far not working.

```
while True:
now = datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%M), end = " ", flush = true)
time.sleep(1)

currentMin = now.srtftime("%M")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that worked for me:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

past_min = None

while True:

  #current min
  now_min = int(datetime.now().strftime("%M"))

  #first iteration
  if not past_min:
    past_min = now_min

  if now_min != past_min:
    #call your function here
    print("Min change detected")


  past_min = now_min

  #print the seconds
  print(datetime.now().strftime("%S"))

  time.sleep(1.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a class (in the below example `Minute`) with a property `currenMin` to store the current minute value. By using `@<property>.setter` function, when the property `<property>` is changed, it will trigger the `setter` function

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

class Minute(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._currenMin = ''

    @property
    def currentMin(self):
        return self._currenMin

    @currentMin.setter
    def currentMin(self, value):
        if value != self._currenMin:
            # ACTION CODE BELOW
            print('Minute changed')
            self._currenMin = value

minute = Minute()
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%M"), end=" ", flush = True)
    time.sleep(1)
    minute.currentMin = now.strftime("%M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the general case with simple variables, you can't simply do it. There are two simple options to do something similar:

- if you control EVERYTHING that writes it, make them trigger that action
- write code that regularly checks it and triggers the action when it changes
- use language tools like a custom setter (see @user696969's answer)

The first case needs you to control everything that could modify that value. At that point, you might not even need a variable, and just pass the new value (and you can reverse this by having a variable that is always updated). This is a very common pattern, called [Event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), and heavily used for example in UIs, websites (client-side, see [a list of DOM events for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)) and game frameworks (see [pygame's documentation on events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html))

The second-case of writing a loop or checking it regularly can also work, however, there are some downsides to it as well. You probably don't want to write an infinite loop waiting for it to change, especially not in a way that also blocks the changing of that variable, and thus dead-locking the entire program as it's preventing something it's waiting for. If you just check it regularly between other, it might be hard to ensure it will be checked regardless of what else is the program doing. You might use multiple threads for it, but that brings it's own set of problems. You also have to store and update the previous value, so you can compare it. This might be slow or memory-consuming if the variable holds too much data.

You can also use language tools with custom setters. This is clean, but can not be used for any variable, just for class attributes, so you still need some control over the rest of the program.

Generally I'd use the event-driven approach or the setter one, depending on the wider context. However, for such simple cases, the checking is also fine. The simplest solution might event be to remove the need for this entirely.